# Function to return all permutations of its arguments in one data frame?

Tags: r, function, dataframe, arguments, permutation

I have data for multiple years. I have a function that takes a product name, a year and spits out a dataframe containing various descriptors from the database. I want to pass into the function the arguments:

```
Product <- c("A","B")    
Year <- c("2015","2016")
```

and for it to calculate all permutations of those arguments, returning a single dataframe. I've tried using mapply and rbind but it turns out all messy. Any advice?

Comment: `expand.grid(Product, Year)`

Comment: Hey, thanks for that function. R continues to amaze be with it's built in functions. Now how would I apply that to my function?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your function is? You state you want a function that returns a data.frame of the permutations of your arguments. Here is one such function: `f <- function(prod, year) expand.grid(prod, year)`

Comment: So I have another function that I would like to run through each of these permutations (eg find_product_sales(product, year) -> returns data frame of all sales for that year of that product) and return a single dataframe with the results of each run through

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `crossing` from tidyr, `pmap` from purrr, and `unnest` from tidyr:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

crossings <- crossing(Product, Year)
crossings$result <- pmap(crossings, find_product_sales)
crossings <- unnest(crossings, result)
```

This is assuming, as you describe in the comments, that the `find_product_sales` function takes a product and year and returns a data frame.

(Note that you could use `expand.grid` instead of `crossing`, but you'd probably want to add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` as well).

Answer (score 1):

First, create the permutations of your arguments

```
params <- expand.grid(Product=Product, Year=Year, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Then split it into a list of arguments

```
params <- split(params, seq.int(nrow(params)))
```

Have a function that takes Product and Year

```
my_func <- function(Product, Year) {
  sprintf("Product: %s, Year: %s", Product, Year)
}
```

Finally, loop over the params and apply your function

```
lapply(params, function(x) do.call(my_func, x))
```