# Expanding all unique combinations of author-author by group, in tidyr

Tags: r, dplyr, combinations, tidyr

I have a dataframe with information from a message board. The data looks like this:

```
    require(dplyr)
    require(tidyr)
    df <- data.frame(author = c(2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024),
             topic = c(101,101,101,101,301,301,501,501,501,501),
             time = c("2014-08-16 20:20:11", "2014-08-16 21:10:00", "2014-08-17 06:30:10",
                        "2014-08-17 10:08:32", "2014-08-20 22:23:01","2014-08-20 23:03:03",
                        "2014-08-25 17:05:01", "2014-08-25 19:15:10",  "2014-08-25 20:07:11",
                        "2014-08-25 23:59:59"))
```

I want to find all the unique combinations of author by topic. My goal is to create an undirected graph with edges categorized by topic and time frame. I use the following code to get this:

```
test <- df %>% group_by(topic) %>% expand(nesting(author), author)
print(test, n = 20)

# A tibble: 36 x 3
# Groups:   topic [3]
topic author author1
    <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  101.     2.      2.
 2  101.     2.      4.
 3  101.     2.      8.
 4  101.     2.     16.
 5  101.     4.      2.
 6  101.     4.      4.
 7  101.     4.      8.
 8  101.     4.     16.
 9  101.     8.      2.
10  101.     8.      4.
11  101.     8.      8.
12  101.     8.     16.
13  101.    16.      2.
14  101.    16.      4.
15  101.    16.      8.
16  101.    16.     16.
17  301.    32.     32.
18  301.    32.     64.
19  301.    64.     32.
20  301.    64.     64.
```

I need help for two things:

1. How do I remove swapped combinations (e.g. row 2 and 5)?
2. For each combination, I would like to have attributes:

   - `start` = earliest post for topic (use mutate, min = min(time))
   - `duration` of topic (time for last post on topic minus time for first post on topic, use mutate duration = max(time) - min(time))
   - count of `posts` (use summarize)?

Comment: What exactly do you want to get? Group by topic, then generate every distinct author1-author2 combination? even where author1==author2?

Comment: I don't understand the second question *"2. For each combination, I would like to have attributes..."*, did you want to generate those new columns in a second (summary) table, or in the same combination expansion table? But anyway, you're supposed to **show us your code attempts**, or at very minimum an example of the output.

Comment: Btw, there's no such thing as *"swapped combinations"*, they're "permutations" (because they're order-dependent). Functions named `expand/expand.grid...` and SQL joins generally give you permutations, not combinations.

Comment: Ok can you accept some answer on this? The big-O runtime(/memory) performance of `combn(x, m=2)` for long x of length (say) 1000 or more is a separate question, please ask it. I suspect the limiting factor is your memory usage not CPU, and as I mentioned the solution is either use file-backed object, or split your big `groupby(datetime)` into as many disjoint chunks of `datetime` as you need. There's no reason to keep the entire result in memory at the same time. But anyway those are separate questions.

Comment: As to memory usage, you're storing your datetime as a string (120 bytes); POSIXct would occupy something like ~520 bytes and POSIXlt ~1816 bytes, but `object.size(as.integer(as.POSIXct("2014-08-16 20:20:11")))` is only 48 bytes (seconds since epoch).

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily want to use `tidyr::expand()` (it seems to be a left-join) to try to generate **combinations**, you seem to be getting all the **permutations** instead: In particular, the unwanted self-self combinations, and combinations with author1,author2 swapped (i.e. permutations). Similarly the builtin `base::expand.grid()` does permutations not combinations.

Use the builtin `combn()` (it's in `utils::combn()`).

There are many existing questions on `dplyr` `groupby` `combn`, you can find them with a simple search.

Been trying to post working code but I don't know `tidyr` so well, everything I tried didn't work or syntax error. `expand` wants a dataframe then it references variables. So `%>% expand(author, author)` again gives you all permutations, not just combinations. `%>% complete(...)` seems useless. I think you need the tidyr syntax to call `combn` on `author` at that grouping level. That might need to be a nested subcall for each grouping level, with whatever tidyr's equivalent of do.call is.

Comment: Yes, I did experience this. I will give this a bash! Thank you.

Comment: Differentiating between permutations and combinations is helpful. My only issue is with combn is that I need to abandon my piped approach (I like the tidyverse method) and run a loop to do unique combinations by group. The combn function is not super intuitive for a beginner like me.

Comment: Bearing in mind you want `combn` not `expand/expand.grid`, see duplicates like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910553/apply-all-permutations-of-arguments-to-function-to-make-one-data-frame for hacked-up tidyr approach. As i say you might have to generate the dataframe/list of author-author combinations as a nested subcall.

Comment: Another way is to suck the result into igraph and simplify undirected graph (remove duplicate edges). It is a hack.

Comment: combn works well on small data sets. When I run this on full message board, I run into memory issues. My solution worked a charm on my small dummy dataset. Have to figure out how to manage memory in R.

Comment: For what input length n did `combn` give memory trouble? Did it only happen when you transposed the output?

Comment: My piped command transposed it. I have 6000 records with 1000 authors across 400 discussions (topic). My script produces 400 undirected networks (one for each topic). This amounts to 80 million edges!

Comment: Ah, you never said the example above was just sample data. What's the longest length `posts = n()` you have to handle? If you want to raise a separate question about the big-O runtime(/memory) performance of `combn(x, m=2)` for x of length (say) 1000 then do. We don't need the author numbers. The `vector x = 1:1000` will do fine. Is your limiting factor CPU or memory? If it's memory, then all bets are off, you either use file-backed object, or split your big calculation into as many disjoiint chunks as you need. There's no reason to keep the entire result into memory at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Final solution:

```
time <- df %>% group_by(topic) %>% mutate(posts = n(), start = min(time), duration = (max(time) - min(time))/3600) %>% distinct(topic,start,duration)
combo <- df %>% group_by(topic) %>% do(data.frame(t(combn(.$author,2))))
edges <- right_join(combo, time)
edges

# A tibble: 13 x 5
# Groups:   topic [?]
   topic    X1    X2 start               duration         
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dttm>              <time>           
 1  101.    2.    4. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 2  101.    2.    8. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 3  101.    2.   16. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 4  101.    4.    8. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 5  101.    4.   16. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 6  101.    8.   16. 2014-08-16 20:20:11 13.8058333333333 
 7  301.   32.   64. 2014-08-20 22:23:01 0.667222222222222
 8  501.  128.  256. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111 
 9  501.  128.  512. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111 
10  501.  128. 1024. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111 
11  501.  256.  512. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111 
12  501.  256. 1024. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111 
13  501.  512. 1024. 2014-08-25 17:05:01 6.91611111111111
```

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved my problem this way:

```
test <- df %>% group_by(topic) %>%
            mutate(posts=n(), start=min(time), duration=(max(time)-min(time))/3600) %>%
            expand(nesting(author), author, posts, start, duration) %>% filter(author != author1)
test
# A tibble: 36 x 6
# Groups:   topic [3]
   topic author author1 posts start               duration
   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <dttm>                 <dbl>
 2  101.     2.      4.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 3  101.     2.      8.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 4  101.     2.     16.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 5  101.     4.      2.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 7  101.     4.      8.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 8  101.     4.     16.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
 9  101.     8.      2.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
10  101.     8.      4.     4 2014-08-16 20:20:11     13.8
# ... with 26 more rows
```

Still need to figure out swapped combinations!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the iterpc package. It is fast and does combinations. Here is my example code:

```
df <- data.frame(author_id = c(2,4,8,16,32,16,128,256,512,8),
             topic_id = c(101,101,101,101,301,301,501,501,501,501),
             time = as.POSIXct(c("2014-08-16 20:20:11", "2014-08-16 21:10:00", "2014-08-17 06:30:10",
                                 "2014-08-17 10:08:32", "2014-08-20 22:23:01","2014-08-20 23:03:03",
                                 "2014-08-25 17:05:01", "2014-08-25 19:15:10",  "2014-08-25 20:07:11",
                                 "2014-08-25 23:59:59")))
```

First I create a unique list of nodes (graph vertices)

```
node <- df %>% distinct(author_id, vendor) %>% rename(id = author_id)
```

Then I create my edge list using iterpc as follows:

```
library(iterpc)
edge <- df %>% group_by(topic_id) %>% do(data.frame(getall(iterpc(table(.$author_id), 2, replace =TRUE)))) %>%
 filter(X1 != X2) %>% rename(from = X1, to = X2) %>% select(to, from, topic_id)
```

That done I build my graph:

```
library(igraph)
test_net <- graph_from_data_frame(d = edge, directed = F, vertices = node)
plot(test_net)
```